# UISegmentedControl - how to toggle between 2 UITableViews

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tab bar based application.
What is the best way to toggle between 2 different UITableView views?

Should I use a wrapper view and add those 2 views to it and depending on which segment
was chosen I will show the correct view?

Using only one tableView will not work because the layout is different between those 
2 tableviews.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a segment to switch views in a Tab Bar app?  Using he tab bar is more logical.  Also, it's really not hard to use the same table view to display different layouts, although usually I agree that it is undesirable.

Comment: I want to display 2 different tables on the same tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

I usually take a different approach: I prefer to use different dataSources for a single instance of tableView and then switching between them (usually by selecting a different index on a segmentedControl).
Again, just to give you a sample:

```
MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
...
id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
}
```

then in the implementation file:

```
[...]

    dataSourceIndex = indexValue;

    NSString *currentClassName  = [classNameModels objectAtIndex:indexValue];
    Class currentClass = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:currentClassName];
    dataSource = [[currentClass alloc] initWithController:self];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Regards.